# Mysql2::Error: Table during unit testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I had done a lynda.com tutorial that created a simlple cms using rails. I wanted to practice and expand my knowledge of rails a bit more by adding the unit testing. But every time I try to run any test I get a mysql error. One example of this is just trying to get the index on the public controller.

```
#public_controller_test.br
test "should get index" do
  get public_index_url
  assert_response :success
end
```

It gives me the following error

```
PublicControllerTest#test_should_get_index:
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Table 'simple_cms_test.users' doesn't exist: DELETE FROM `users`
```

If you need to look at more of the code it is available at
https://github.com/trmccormick/rails_simple_cms Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: your test db doesn't exist, run rake db:test:prepare

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this problem out on my own. The issue was in the fixtures I had a file users.yml it should have been admin_users.yml so the users table was never getting loaded with fake users so it was failing. Renaming the file corrected the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Error says you don't have table `users` in your `simple_cms_test` database.

So you need to sync your test db with dev db.

Run `rake db:migrate test` 
or `rake db:schema:load test` and everything should work fine.